# jQuery cookie persistence

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to successfully add cookies to a jQuery Ajax application on a website.

But, my very short question is, **how can I set the cookie to exist indefinately?**

I am trying to remember users preferences settings by storing them long term in a cookie containing an array of data unique to each user.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use localstorage to store your data and send it as a cookie whenever you want.

Answer (score 15):

You can't set a cookie to exist indefinitely. You make a cookie persistent by setting an expiration date on it, and as the expiration date has to have a specific value, that's when the cookie will expire.

You can make the cookie live for a year, for example:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 365 });
```

You can also use a `Date` object for the expiration date, but you should keep the date on this side of year 2038, as some systems doesn't support dates after that yet.

Comment: Yep, that's what I found after some googling - unfortunately. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't set a cookie to "never" expire, but you can do just as good.

Usually I prefer to set cookies for 30 days, and renew them whenever the user accesses a page. As long as the user doesn't leave for a month, the cookie is permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to set the expire option to : 9999. Which could be a solution for you.

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 9999 });
```

But there is no valid option for infinite.

Just try to experiment with the values. But is it a good Idea to save it to cookies ? Because if the user somewhen delets the cookies there gone anyway. Did you consider saving the "properties" to a database ?