# Keep jquery cookie value through pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I'm using jquery cookie lib to remember a state for a certain div on my pages. This div is shown on all the website pages.

Here is my code :

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
     $('#notes-content').slideToggle('slow', function(){
       if($(this).is(":visible")){
         $.cookie('note', "yes");
       }else{
         $.cookie('note',"non");
       }
     });
```

The problem is, when i click on #btn in the page A, and i try the code

```
alert($.cookie('note'));
```

I obtain "yes"
Then i go to the page B, and i try the same alert, i obtain "undefined"

How do i keep the value of the cookie through all the website pages ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9467002/3130094

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery cookie persistence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466829/jquery-cookie-persistence)

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, the value of my cookie is not the same through the pages, on some pages i got "yes", on others i got "non"

Comment: Solved with setting the cookie path to /